# Link fragment button to another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

**Below is the EDITED code**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.btn_chg_password:
            showDialog();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_order:
            changemenu();
            break;
    }
}

private void changemenu() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN,false);
    editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL,"");
    editor.putString(Constants.NAME,"");
    editor.putString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID,"");
    editor.apply();
    order();
}

private void order(){

    Fragment login = new LoginFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.activity_activityresult1,activityresult1);
    ft.commit();
```

i want to change the link to activity_activityresult1 after i press **btn_order** I believe i cannot just link it like this because its fragment to activity? on clicking the **btn_order** i want to direct to the *activity_activityresult1* <----- this layout

**Below is the original code**

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.btn_chg_password:
            showDialog();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_logout:
            logout();
            break;
    }
}

private void logout() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN,false);
    editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL,"");
    editor.putString(Constants.NAME,"");
    editor.putString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID,"");
    editor.apply();
    goToLogin();
}

private void goToLogin(){

    Fragment login = new LoginFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame,login);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: Do yu want to navigate back to activity from the button click which your method order() tries to reflect

Comment: Do you want to open an activity from Fragment (on click of a button in fragment)?

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve? Please make it bit more clearer

Comment: @Haroon on clicking the **btn_order** i want to direct to the activity_activityresult1 <----- this layout

Comment: @AshishTiwari  on clicking the btn_order i want to direct to the activity_activityresult1 <----- this layout

Comment: @AlokNair  on clicking the btn_order i want to direct to the activity_activityresult1 <----- this layout

Comment: @Vyshunavi If you are using fragments to display your login and main view, then initialize your Login fragment just like in the original code and replace it  in the fragment area. If it is another activity, then start that activity via intent and finish the current activity. In your code "activityresult1" is not initialized at all to be replaced into fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void order(){
  Intent mIntent = new Intent();
  mIntent.setClassName(your_package_name_string, your_activity_name_string);
  // for ex: your package name can be "com.example"
  // your activity name will be "com.example.Contact_Developer"
  startActivity(myIntent);

  or 
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), TargetActivity.class);
 startActivity(myIntent);
 }
```

Use this if you mean to navigate to activity from the Order button click of fragment  hope this helps.